# Cannot switch keyboard layout under i3 wm

Tags: 14.04, gnome, keyboard-layout, ibus, i3-wm

I've recently decided to give ubuntu a try again. So far everything works fine except one strange detail.

I have ibus autostarted and sitting into my tray of i3 wm, but I didn't start it. 
my addions to the .i3/config are only following lines:

```
exec syndaemon -i 1 -K -d
exec nm-applet &
exec --no-startup-id nitrogen --restore
exec sleep 4 && xmodmap -e "keycode 107=Insert"
exec gnome-settings-daemon
```

More importantly pressing combination for switching layouts shows small windows which highlight switch to different layout, but nonetheless I still using default English one.

On linux-mint I've had the similar setup with only difference I did

```
exec cinnamon-settings-daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your input method with im-config (start as user). Set it to none and it go away.